# Dynamic_sidebar load in string makeup

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

in my theme the header is loaded through a string (i think thats correct) like below and iv been trying to add a sidebar into it but its only showing the number '1' ?

How do i manage to get working?

```
$menu_markup = '<header class="%s header"> ' . dynamic_sidebar('header-widget') . ' <a href="%s">%s</a> </div>';
```

Comment: The result rather depends upon what `dynamic_sidebar()` does. Are you using a CMS or Framework or is this all your code

Comment: its Wordpress,  the only thing being rendered on the front-end is "1"

Comment: @RiggsFolly any idea with using Wp ?